# How can I get the result Refs. [1,2-4] in the given code?

Tags: bibliographies, citing, cite-package

I am using this code for citations

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{cite}

\begin{document}

Refs. \cite{a,b-d}
   
\begin{thebibliography}{}

\bibitem{a}
a

\bibitem{b}
b

\bibitem{c}
c

\bibitem{d}
d
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

but it gives me this result

[image]

How can I get the result Refs. [1,2-4]?

Comment: You can have "[1-4]" from `\cite{a,b,c,d}`, but I don't think there is an easy way to "exclude" certain entries from the compress function. `[\citenum{a}, \citenum{b,c,d}]` (or more macro-y `\citeleft\citenum{a}\citepunct\citenum{b,c,d}\citeright`) works, but isn't particularly elegant.

Comment: @moewe Thanks, it does the job for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have "[1-4]" from `\cite{a,b,c,d}`, but I am not aware of an easy way to "exclude" certain entries from the compress feature.

You can use `\citenum` to build the desired output ad hoc

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{cite}

\begin{document}
Refs.~\cite{a,b,c,d}

Refs.~\citeleft\citenum{a}\citepunct\citenum{b,c,d}\citeright

\begin{thebibliography}{4}

\bibitem{a}
a

\bibitem{b}
b

\bibitem{c}
c

\bibitem{d}
d
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

[image: Refs. [1–4] Refs. [1,2–4]]

Here is an implementation of a `\cites` command that lets you separate "chunks" of citations across which there is no compression.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{cite}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\bool_new:N \g__mtwentytwentyone_firstitem_bool

\NewDocumentCommand{\cites}{ >{ \SplitList {;} } m }
  {
    \citeleft
    \bool_gset_true:N \g__mtwentytwentyone_firstitem_bool
    \ProcessList { #1 } { \citesprocess }
    \citeright
  }

\NewDocumentCommand{\citesprocess}{m}
  {
    \bool_if:NTF \g__mtwentytwentyone_firstitem_bool
      { \bool_gset_false:N \g__mtwentytwentyone_firstitem_bool } 
      { \citepunct }
    \citenum{#1}
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
Refs.~\cites{a;b,c,d;e}

Refs.~\cites{a;b,c,d}

Refs.~\cites{a,b,c,d}

\begin{thebibliography}{4}

\bibitem{a}
a

\bibitem{b}
b

\bibitem{c}
c

\bibitem{d}
d

\bibitem{e}
e
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

[image: Refs. [1,2–4,5] Refs. [1,2–4] Refs. [1–4]]

Note that this needs a reasonably new LaTeX or `\usepackage{xparse}`.